# Android Noise reduction

Tags: android, java

just want to ask on how can I apply a noise reduction in my recorded audio. Well I already created a recorder but one problem is that I used MediaRecorder instead of AudioRecorder. Now I think about adding the noise reduction by altering my recorded audio then replacing the existing record after recording but don't know how to do it. Is theres a way I can do it while recording or is my plan possible?

Maybe someone can give me a steps on how to do it or a tutorial link can do. But I think it would be best if you can recommend some java jar library I can use for this (opensource and free to use).

I used 3gpp output encoded in AMR_NB for the recorded audio by the way and as mentioned I used MediaRecorder for recording of audio source from mic.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started)'s NS module. but it's input is PCM, so you need a little transformat. and you should compile the NS module and wrap it into JNI interface yourself, cus' WebRTC has no such jar libraries right now.